# Python - unexpected behaviour when using a named constructor argument with empty list default value

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

I'm obviously missing something here: can anyone explain why `t1` "mysteriously" acquires the `self.thelist` value of `t2`? What am I doing wrong?

```
>>> class ThingyWithAList(object):
...     def __init__(self, alist=[]):
...         super(ThingyWithAList, self).__init__()
...         self.thelist = alist
... 
>>> t1 = ThingyWithAList()
>>> t1.thelist.append('foo')
>>> t1.thelist.append('bar')
>>> print t1, t1.thelist
<__main__.ThingyWithAList object at 0x1004a8350> ['foo', 'bar']
>>> 
>>> t2 = ThingyWithAList()
>>> print t2, t2.thelist
<__main__.ThingyWithAList object at 0x1004a8210> ['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: check this anwser : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: @mouad - excellent, thanks! I did poke around on SO before posting this question but didn't spot this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the default argument 'alist=[]', creates only one list, once, when the module is read. This single list becomes the default argument for that __init__", and is shared by all your Thingys.

Try using None as a dummy symbol meaning "make a new empty list here".  E.g.

```
def __init__(self, alist=None):
     super(ThingyWithAList, self).__init__()
     self.thelist = [] if alist is None else alist
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian; great, succinct answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right, the object reference created with `[]` in the constructor remains the same.  Try this instead:

```
>>> class ThingyWithAList(object):
...     def __init__(self, alist=None):
...         super(ThingyWithAList, self).__init__()
...         self.thelist = alist or []
... 
>>> t1 = ThingyWithAList()
>>> t1.thelist.append('foo')
>>> t1.thelist.append('bar')
>>> print t1, t1.thelist
<__main__.ThingyWithAList object at 0xb75099ac> ['foo', 'bar']
>>> 
>>> t2 = ThingyWithAList()
>>> print t2, t2.thelist
<__main__.ThingyWithAList object at 0xb7509a6c> []
```

Comment: Your  "alist or []" better than my "[] if alist is None else alist".  In Perl I automatically think of that kind of syntax, in Python it seems like a Perlism.

Comment: I guess I’ve been too long into Perl to do it any other way. ;-)

Comment: Excellent, thanks! (It's OK, I still think in Perl from time to time. :-))

Comment: It's very unlikely it matters, but this will result in thelist being set to a new, empty list if it is passed an empty container. So you can't set thelist to be a container you already have a reference to (such as one that is an attribute of another object) this way. It's better to check against `None` since that's what you really mean.

Answer (score 2):

"Special cases aren't special enough", so checking conditionally for None rubs me the wrong way. If it's important that `.thelist` really is a list, then the class ought to enforce that itself, too.

```
def __init__(self, alist=()):
    super(ThingyWithAList, self).__init__()
    self.thelist = list(alist)
```

Note that there is no danger of modifying the default arg now, because tuples are immutable.